# Handing Categorical Variables in Machine Learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, categorical-data

I have data of the form:

Feature 1   Feature 2 Feature 3   ---> Numerical Value

Problem is Feature 1 is like, String Values like Company Names, Feature 2 is also a string value like a Category and Feature 3 is just timestamp.

I want to train a model that given the features is able to predict the numerical value.

I know regression can be used for it.

But,

1. How do I convert the categorical features so that they can be used in regression?
2. How do I utilize the timestamp value for Prediction? Should I extract the month, the hour number (line from 0-23) and make them into more categorical values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As we know machine learning algorithm are not capable to understand the text directly,so we need to convert these string values into one hot vector representation.

we use one hot encoder to perform “binarization” of the category and include it as a feature to train the model

So you can use pandas for this,
For example

```
import pandas as pd 
df =pd.DataFrame({'A':["google","amazon","microsoft"]})

pd.get_dummies(df)

    A_amazon    A_google    A_microsoft
     0              1          0
     1              0          0
     0              0          1
```

After converting your variable into above format you can apply regression
Thanks